# Is Google Firebase's plan policy "per account" or "per project"?

Tags: firebase

Is Google Firebase's plan policy "per account" or "per project"?

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=ko&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzL3kkYTQ5wIV16iWCh18mQPqEAAYASABEgKhuPD_BwE

Can I use N 'SPARK PLAN' with multiple apps with one Google account from the point of view of freetire usage?
Or are you wondering if one Google account shares one free tier of spark plan?

Comment: Project :-) - one app - one project - one plan - one Béart - one soul

Comment: OneProject { A-app : "spark plan-1" , B-app : "blaze plan". C-app:"spark plan-2" } is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The free quota limits you see on the pricing page for the Spark plan is per project.  However, there are a limited number of Spark projects that you can have for a single Google account. The exact number is determine per account using some algorithm Google decides.